# Why is my dog losing all his hair?

Tags: dogs, health, hairloss

Our Boston is losing hair, bottom half of him is hair-less, now his back is starting to bald.  We have been to our vet, skin tests, blood tests, no answers. Our Veterinarian suggested Possible Allergy. We have been doing elimination diet with him.  The only symptom that makes allergies seem incorrect, is that nearly once a day he jumps up and Yelps like something just bit his insides!  ANY SUGGESTIONS??  (He is on Melatonin)
THANKS ALL!!**W**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Pet Exchange Connie, have you been to another vet to get a second opinion?

Comment: When did he first start to lose hair? Is the hairless skin smooth and elastic or is it dry, spotted red, itchy, scabbed or anything else? Has the vet checked for skin mites and other parasites?

Comment: Our Veterinarian suggested Possible Allergy?